# How to implement database logic using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I do have a question regarding EF and databases. I am upgrading my application from former Ado.net to EF but in my code major business logic has been written at the database level.

My question is whether I need to have shift that logic from the database level to code level if I want to use EF, or if I can go with the same database logic with EF.

For example, one of my requirements is:

```
#Procedure#
CREATE PROCEDURE Getemp123
    (@gender VARCHAR(40))
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@gender = 'Male')
        SELECT
            D.Name, E.FirstName, E.Salary  
        FROM
            Employees E 
        LEFT JOIN
            Departments D ON D.ID = E.DepartmentId 
        WHERE 
            Gender = @gender
    ELSE
        SELECT 
            D.ID, E.FirstName, E.LastName  
        FROM
            Employees E 
        LEFT JOIN
            Departments D ON D.ID = E.DepartmentId 
        WHERE 
            Gender = @gender
END
```

But when I am using EF, then it will create class for `if()` condition not for else requirement #

Class:

```
public partial class Getemp123_Result
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you gaining by converting to EF? Are you sure you need to convert everything? You can still use both methods together in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your project is migrating from WinForm App with current existing database and stored procedure.

You should **only select tables** (do not select stored procedure) when generate EF Designer from database.

And you can define your `ViewModel` like

```
class YourType
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public string FirstName  { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int? Salary { get; set; }
}
```

In your Business Logic you can handle logic like

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@gender", "male");
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<YourType>("exec Getemp123 @gender", param1);
```

Another way if you don't want to create `YourType`, you can use dynamic object.

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>("exec Getemp123 @gender", param1);

foreach(var item in result)
{
     var firstname = item.FirstName;
     //check property in dynamic before using
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution . definitely this will work for my requirement